# How to combine list of X and list of Y into one (X,Y) list?

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
X = [1.4 ,3.2, 5.8, 2.1, 3.5]
Y = [2.1, 5.6, 1.2, 1.3, 4.6]
```

How can I make one array from everything in `X` and `Y`?

I have tried this:

```
for i in X:
    X_Y[i] = {X[i], Y[i]}
```

But it gives me an error `list indices must be integers or slices, not float`

So then I tried `zip` but it just gave me a location `zip at ...`

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip` and list comprehension to get a list of (X, Y) tuples.

```
XY = [i for i in zip(X, Y)]
# [(1.4, 2.1), (3.2, 5.6), (5.8, 1.2), (2.1, 1.3), (3.5, 4.6)]
```

**Shorter version** (See also Nathan's solution below)

```
XY = list(zip(X, Y))
```

**Problem in your solution**: When you do `for i in X:`, you are basically iterating over the individual elements of `X`. So in the first iteration, `i` will be `1.4` and then you do `X_Y[i]`. First problem is that you didn't initialize the empty list `X_Y` and second, the indices for the list cannot be float. Moreover, to add elements to a list, you use `append`. `X[i], Y[i]` for the first iteration means `X[1.4], Y[1.4]` which is incorrect.

---

**How to make your code work?**

You initialize an empty list first. Then you iterate over the length of the `X` and `Y` lists and then `append` each pair one by one as following:

```
X_Y = []
for i in range(len(X)):
    X_Y.append((X[i], Y[i]))
```

A **one liner** for these three lines of code using list comprehension would be

```
X_Y = [(X[i], Y[i]) for i in range(len(X))]
```

**Another one liner** using `map` and `lambda` function. Here you create a lambda function which takes two arguments: `x` and `y` and performs operation `(x, y)` element wise on the actual lists `X` and `Y`. `list()` acts on the mapped generator to get you the final list `X_Y`.

```
X_Y = list(map(lambda x, y: (x, y), X, Y))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use zip like this:

```
X = [1.4 ,3.2, 5.8, 2.1, 3.5]
Y = [2.1, 5.6, 1.2, 1.3, 4.6]
X_Y = list(zip(X, Y))
print(X_Y)
```

Which returns

```
[(1.4, 2.1), (3.2, 5.6), (5.8, 1.2), (2.1, 1.3), (3.5, 4.6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
for i in X:
```

the for loop iterates through your X list. So, i will be 1.4, 3.2, ..., 3.5. So, the error is correct, because you're using float values as indexes. A quick fix would be

```
for i in range(len(X)):
```

this generates a list from 0 to your list length and it is a integer index now.

Also, if you want a shorter version, you can use

```
xy = list(zip(x,y))
```

to concatenate your x and y. Also, if you ever want to disassociate it back, just use

```
x, y = zip(*xy)

# You have to do the following because zip(*xy) returns tuples instead of lists
x = list(x)
y = list(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use extend:

```
xy =[]
for i in range(len(x)):
    xy.extend([x[i],y[i]])
```

Answer (score -1):

You are on the right track, it is simply a matter of creating a dictionary, and using the update() function to append the new values to the dictionary as Key,Value pairs.

Create empty dict

```
X_Y = {}
```

Create arrays

```
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Y = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Loop in range of values in X
and append values to dict

```
for i in range(len(X)):
    X_Y.update({X[i]:Y[i]}
```

The elements in the first array become the keys in the dictionary, and the elements in the second array become the values.

Print key:values in the dict

```
for k,v in X_Y.items():
print(k, v)
```

Comment: this seems a bit complicated a solution that does not really answer the question asked imo. The final ouput should be an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: Good point on the array, however since other solutions give a list of tuples, the effect is much the same. As for the solution I do not believe it to be over complicated, the solution is almost identical to the code written by the OP, and is well explained.